# R best vizualization

Tags: r, plot, visualization

I would like to do vizualisation of 2 vectors (predikcia & test data) of all wrongly classified numbers from my classification problem, where i have 76 data in both vectors - first one (predikcia) has numbers from 0-9 what classificator wrongly predicted and in second vector (test data) are numbers what it should be. Basic plot of these vectors has not good representation or not giving some good information about what numbers were wrongly classified and what number they should be classified correctly. Here is a picture what is basic plot showing
[image: plot(a,b)]

data

```
classres <- data.frame(
  predikcia = c(9L, 8L, 3L, 9L, 1L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 
    6L, 3L, 5L, 9L, 8L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 9L, 
    5L, 1L, 8L, 9L, 5L, 0L, 1L, 9L, 5L, 5L, 8L, 9L,
    2L, 5L, 8L, 5L, 6L, 9L, 9L, 4L, 9L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 4L, 3L,    
    5L, 8L, 3L, 0L, 5L, 8L, 8L, 7L, 3L, 8L, 8L, 5L, 9L, 9L, 1L, 5L, 5L,
    9L, 9L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 9L, 2L, 5L, 8L, 9L),
  testdata = c(4L, 6L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 
   9L, 7L, 8L, 0L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 7L, 1L, 9L, 5L, 8L,
   8L, 0L, 5L, 1L, 8L, 4L, 1L, 9L, 1L, 0L, 5L, 1L,
   9L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 7L, 5L, 9L, 8L, 5L,
   5L, 5L, 1L, 9L, 9L, 0L, 9L, 8L, 9L, 6L, 0L, 8L,
   5L, 0L, 9L, 8L, 5L, 5L, 9L, 2L, 8L, 0L, 5L, 7L,
   1L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 7L, 1L))
```

Comment: Dont post images. Post the data

Comment: All of them were wronly classified

Comment: Add a diagonal line to indicate what is "correct"? You give no indication of whether these are categorical, ordinal, or continuous, and how to show them can be predicated on knowing that. Further ... so what? This is 20 rows out of "how many"? Is this a significant portion of your data? What is the impact of these mis-classifications? Is the difference meaningful, meaning `1`-vs-`9` is much worse than `1`-vs-`2`?

Comment: @r2evans thank you for reply, point of this is to know what numbers were classified wrongly which numbers were most problematic to classify.  This 76 are what he classified badly from 1500 test data, so overall % of success is good, i need to analyze wrong classifications -  in what numbers he missed and maybe see some number which he had problems to classify

Comment: Categorical/ordinal/continuous? Is the magnitude of difference relevant? Is each row relevant in its own way (i.e., *"on question 3a which has to do with counting dog years, the answer is incorrect; on question 4b where the respondent type their name, they misplaced 3 letters"*), or are they effectively equivalent weighting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that there is either "correct" or "incorrect" predictions, otherwise the graph would need more work.

First, I have the data in which there are precitions and real values. In this examle they are integers, but I'm pretending that it does not mean anything.

```
classres <- data.frame(
  predikcia = c(9L, 8L, 3L, 9L, 1L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 
                6L, 3L, 5L, 9L, 8L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 9L), 
  testdata = c(4L, 6L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 
               9L, 7L, 8L, 0L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 7L, 1L, 9L, 5L))
```

Then I create a count data-frame. The "factor" part is important because I want all the possible combinations to appear on the plot.

```
dat.plot <- classres %>% 
  count(testdata, predikcia) %>% 
  mutate(
    testdata = factor(testdata, levels = 0:9),
    predikcia = factor(predikcia, levels = 0:9))
```

Finally, I create a heatmap from the data coloring the inside of each cell with the count values and adding a border to the cells where predictions are considered correct (this is why I need the `goodclass` data-frame).

```
goodclass <- data.frame(
  testdata = factor(0:9),
  predikcia = factor(0:9)
)

dat.plot %>%
  ggplot(aes(testdata, predikcia, fill = n)) +
  geom_tile() + 
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "goldenrod", high = "darkorchid4") + 
  geom_tile(data = goodclass, 
            aes(testdata, predikcia, color = "Correct\npredictions"), 
            inherit.aes = FALSE, fill = NA, size = 2) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c(`Correct\npredictions` = "limegreen")) + 
  labs(x = "Real class value", y = "Predicted class value", 
       fill = "count", color = "") +
  coord_equal() + 
  theme_minimal() + 
  theme(
    panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor = element_line(color = "black", size = 2))
```

And the results hurst a little bit the eyes: it will probably need  little bit more work to find more beautiful colors.

[image: Heatmap for predictions]

Comment: thank you, this was helpful and i can see my classificator mostly missclasified number 1 to numbers 2 and 3 and  another problematic is 5 vs. 9, thanks

Comment: I'm glad I could help, please accept the answer